# Битрикс: нет настроек почтовых ящиков

Tags: битрикс, email

1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 15.0.6

Кто-то до меня создал несколько почтовых ящиков, они работают. Мне нужно изменить их пароли, однако **нигде** в ПУ нет секции с настройками почты.
Официальный модуль Почты также не установлен.

Документацию читал: 
Сервисы > Почта > Почтовые ящики (Пункт 'Почта' отсутствует)

Comment: Почтовые адреса и пароли настраиваются, скорее всего, на почтовом сервере у регистратора домена

Answer (score 2):

В битриксе есть возможность читать сообщения из почтовых ящиков, но нет возможности создавать или редактировать ящики.

Скорее всего почтовые ящики были созданы:

- на сервисе типа pdd.yandex.ru, biz.mail.ru
- на хостинге к которому привязан домен
- свой почтовый сервер